# Exceção url em token Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

No meu projeto estou precisando liberar uma `url` para um serviço `rest` que estou implementando, só que não estou conseguindo fazer a exceção do `token` para essa rota, já que não vou recebe-lo no serviço.

No arquivo VerifyCsrfToken, já está com o atributo $except para a rota, mas não está ajudando:

```
protected $except = [
    'wallet/*'
];
```

Assim é como está o roteamento:

```
Route::post('wallet/apple/v1/devices/{device}/registrations/{registration}/{redNumber}', 'Service\AppleWalletController@register');
```

Continua dando o mesmo erro quando rodo o serviço:

> local.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in /var/www/dufryred.com.br/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:46

Há outro meio de fazer essa exceção do `token` para a minha rota, ou tenho que configurar em outro lugar?

Comment: Cade o seu `route`, o arquivo que é configuradas as rotas?

Comment: Opa, beleza, já editei a questão

Comment: o problema é a rota eu to achando vendo assim por cima, tente por favor (estou no celular) `'wallet/apple/v1/devices/*' para ver se funciona?

Comment: Não, mesmo assim também não funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achei uma solução que deu certo. Segue o código da classe `VerifyCsrfToken`:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier {

/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
protected $excludeRoutes = [
    'wallet*'
];

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    foreach( $this->excludeRoutes as $route )
    {
        if( $request->is( $route ) ) return $next($request);
    }
    return parent::handle($request, $next);
}
```

A rota ficou do mesmo jeito.